how to animation zoom uicollectionview cell and change layout?
At iOS platform,like system "Photos" App，or "Google Photos" App.
Its photo gallery page can animation change photo item size and layout when you pinch gesture at gallery.
Also it only scale finger touch area.
Anybody know how to code like this effect?


Please review [ask]. Have you tried anything? Have you searched for UICollectionView zoom?

@DonMag yeah, I had try to search, but get nothing like the system photos app solution
